# Pipe regex in SQL before a DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, regex, pipe

```
--col1 col2 col3 col4          col5
--A    2.2  red  weapiuheraiub weap
--D    3.1  blue uifhsuiaewfuh uifh
--...  ...  ...  ...
```

I need a SQL regular expression that generates `col5` above based off first four characters of `col4` above. Something along the lines `^(.{4}).*` replace with `\1`. Then I need to pipe it to this "DISTINCT" query shown below:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col5 ORDER BY col5) AS SEQNUM 
FROM table_name t
) t 
WHERE SEQNUM = 1;
```

This "DISTINCT" query keeps only one unique occurrence (the first) of each value for `col5` and filters out the rest. It also preserves all columns in my table.

How do I do create such a pipe in SQL (my desired regex --> to my "DISTINCT" function)? Or do I have to nest? And how would I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to further filter the results based on that value, or just want to output it?

Comment: @Nick just rephrased the question, is that any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `LEFT(col4,4)` to extract the part of `col4` that you want, and use that in the window expression:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*, LEFT(col4, 4) AS col5, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(col4,4) ORDER BY LEFT(col4,4)) AS SEQNUM 
FROM table_name t
) t 
WHERE SEQNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I also need to have `col5` for a future JOIN. Do I just create that after the code you posted? And how? Thanks

Comment: @JasonHunter I've added `col5` to the query. Note that you can't use the alias in the window expression as it is not defined when that expression is evaluated.